# Bash script that creates a file and then copies it - the copy is sometimes empty

Tags: linux, bash, flush

I'm relatively inexperienced at creating bash scripts. I have a script that has the following form:

```
echo "something" >> somefile
echo "somethingelse" >> somefile
rm -f /somepath/somefile
cp somefile /somepath/somefile
```

What this is doing is creating a file (which in the real application is filled with data submitted from a web form) and then copying that file to `/somepath/`.

Sometimes, the copy of the new file is empty, and yet the original copy contains all `echo`ed data.

Is this possibly to do with a race condition, in that the data may not have been flushed to the file prior to the copy operation?

Answer (score 2):

If this is being submitted by a web form I'm guessing you can have multiple threads accessing your temp file at any given time.

What is the ***real*** name of the file you're echoing to, is it unique?

Try appending something unique to that filename, like the process id perhaps.

You can get the process id using: `$$`

```
echo "text" >> "tempfile_$$"
```

Which will give you something like this: tempfile_1234

Or even better you could use a variable:

```
TEMP_FILE="tempfile_$$"
echo "text" >> $TEMP_FILE
# Do other stuff, copying, etc.
rm $TEMP_FILE
```

Comment: Is it run when a Web form is submitted or something? Could it be a race condition e.g. more than one instance of the same script?

Comment: Thanks. The real name is always the same; it's never unique. As bad as this sounds, this is really just a simple embedded web server whose form is unlikely to be accessed from various users simultaneously. I'll try out your suggestion - many thanks!

Comment: There's no other way that your script could be failing as you describe -- something must be overwriting the file.

Comment: To add a bit more info, what it's doing is providing a way for the user of the embedded system (an Arch Linux ARM based SBC) to change its IP address. When the web form is submitted, a script is called to generate a new netctl profile, which is then moved to /etc/netctl/ and then enabled. (If there's a better way I could achieve this entirely then I'd be open to suggestions -- perhaps in a separate question.) I wonder if the netctl system could be trying to access the file at that point. As an aside, changing the `rm` to a `mv` to move rather than copy seems to have eliminated the problem.

Comment: @Jay apologies - I should have got back to this sooner but it has been a busy weekend. I really appreciate your answer. Oddly, the fix seemed to be to simply `mv` the file instead of doing a `mv`. During the tests, I never had the web form accessed simultaneously. What I think I'll do is experiment further to see if I can get to the bottom of what the cause is, and I will ultimately post an answer if I can determine one. I'd say you should leave this answer here though because it is certainly a possible cause for the problem given and it has been useful; I've up-voted accordingly.